# Is there a way to convert pandas columns with list of nested dicts to rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas `dataframe` with a column containing a **list of nested dictionaries**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Column_1" : [
                                 [{'PID': '03', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '01', 'mace': [{'all': 100, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}]}],
                                np.nan,
                                [{'PID': '01', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '02', 'mace': [{'all': 100, 'd_Loc': 'driver side'}]}]}],
                                [{'PID': '01', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '11', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '14', 'mace': [{'all': 23, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '06', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}]}]}, 
                                {'PID': '06', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '11', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]},
                                                        {'PID': '01', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '14', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '10', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}]}]}, 
                                {'PID': '14', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '11', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '01', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '06', 'mace': [{'all': 25, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 100, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '10', 'mace': [{'all': 100, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}]}]}, 
                                {'PID': '11', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '01', 'mace': [{'all': 100, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '14', 'mace': [{'all': 53, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '06', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}]}]}, 
                                {'PID': '10', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '14', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '06', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}]}],
                                [{'PID': '03', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '01', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '06', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '09', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}]}, 
                                {'PID': '06', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '01', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '03', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '09', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}]}, 
                                {'PID': '08', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '01', 'mace': [{'all': 100, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 100, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '03', 'mace': [{'all': 100, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 100, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '06', 'mace': [{'all': 100, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 100, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '09', 'mace': [{'all': 100, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 100, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}]}, 
                                {'PID': '09', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '01', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '03', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '06', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}]}, 
                                {'PID': '01', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '03', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '06', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}, 
                                                        {'PID': '09', 'mace': [{'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'rear'}, 
                                                                                {'all': 0, 'd_Loc': 'front'}]}]}]],
                   "Key" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   "Val_1": [25, 46, 75, 85, 89]})
```

Data:

```
    Column_1                                          Key Val_1
0   [{'PID': '03', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '01', 'mace...   1    25
1   NaN                                                 2    46
2   [{'PID': '01', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '02', 'mace...   3    75
3   [{'PID': '01', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '11', 'mace...   4    85
4   [{'PID': '03', 'Col_par': [{'PID': '01', 'mace...   5    89
```

I want to extract values in the nested dictionaries and transform the nested list of dictionaries into `rows`.

```
PID_Val,  Col_par_PID,  PID_mace_all,  PID_d_loc,  Key,  Val1
'03',            '01',           100,    'front',    1,    25
np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan,     np.nan,    2,    46
'01',            '02',           100,'driver side',  3,    75
'01',            '11',             0,    'front',    4,    85
'01',            '14',            23,     'rear',    4,    85
'01',            '06',             0,     'rear',    4,    85
'06',            '11',             0,    'front',    4,    85
'06',            '01',             0,    'front',    4,    85
'06',            '14',             0,     'rear',    4,    85

  # And soooo on
```

How to transform column of nested dictionaries into pandas rows?

Comment: Due to the somewhat complicated logic behind what column names are concatenated and how, I'm not sure there's a tidy Pandas function that'll do the work for you. It wouldn't be too hard to write an algorithm to parse your data though. What have you tried so far? Actually, looking more closely, where is the column name `PID_Val` coming from?

Comment: `PID_VAL` is the `PID`  value of the first dict in the list

Comment: I get that, but do you have logic for how to rename those columns? Some are just concatenated, like `PID_d_loc` while others seem to follow different rules. Why does `mace` not become `mace_all`? Why is it `PID_mace_all`, but not `PID_mace_d_loc`?

Comment: Most importantly, do you have any control over how you store/receive this data in the first place? This is a very messy structure that would be a lot easier to fix at the source.

Comment: No, I don't have any control over the source, and the column names are renamed for just understanding the values. The only option I have is to normalize the column values to rows. And the column names are not required to follow any rules/logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df = df[['Key', 'Val_1']].join(df['Column_1'].explode().apply(pd.Series)[['Col_par', 'PID']])
df.rename(columns={'PID':'PID_Val'}, inplace=True)
df = df[['Key', 'Val_1', 'PID_Val']].join(df['Col_par'].explode().apply(pd.Series)[['PID', 'mace']])
df.rename(columns={'PID': 'Col_par_PID'}, inplace=True)
df = df[['Key', 'Val_1', 'PID_Val', 'Col_par_PID']].join(df['mace'].explode().apply(pd.Series)[['all', 'd_Loc']])
df.rename(columns={'all': 'PID_mace_all', 'd_Loc': 'PID_d_loc'}, inplace=True)
df = df[['PID_Val', 'Col_par_PID', 'PID_mace_all', 'PID_d_loc', 'Key', 'Val_1']]
```

OUTPUT:

```
   PID_Val Col_par_PID  PID_mace_all    PID_d_loc  Key  Val_1
0       03          01         100.0        front    1     25
1      NaN         NaN           NaN          NaN    2     46
2       01          02         100.0  driver side    3     75
3       01          11           0.0        front    4     85
3       01          11          23.0         rear    4     85
..     ...         ...           ...          ...  ...    ...
4       01          09           0.0        front    5     89
4       01          09           0.0         rear    5     89
4       01          09           0.0        front    5     89
4       01          09           0.0         rear    5     89
4       01          09           0.0        front    5     89
```

Comment: This is excellent & amazing, never thought `join` & `explode` would do this.